# Grup all and terminate total

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have next query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 8day 
FROM ( 
    SELECT data_raport, SUM(ore) as Total_Hours 
    FROM sohy_works 
    WHERE data_raport BETWEEN '" . $_GET['data']."' AND '" . $_GET['data-2'] . "' 
        AND numes LIKE '%" . $_GET['numes'] . "%' 
    GROUP BY data_raport 
    HAVING TOT Total_Hours <= '8:00' ) T
```

That query it's grup all result by having a total of <= 8:00 hours, exemple:

If i have one date with multiple works one with 5hours, second with 3 hours, t with 3 hours and the four with 5 hours result of count it will be 2 of 8 hours but i want to ignor if the total o all works in one date is over 8 hours. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, your question is not understandable for me. Please rephrase. Also you have to use `SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( ore ) ) ) as Total_Hours` to get correct results.

Comment: Be aware of Injeqctions into your Query! NEVER EVER read from $_GET, $_POST $_REQUEST without sanitizing the data very well.